# Does an ASP.net MVC project support adding Dynamic Data?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, dynamic-data

Does an ASP.net MVC project support adding Dynamic Data?

If so, any links/pointers to doco that gives an overview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeas, support.

Please, read this [great article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx).

Also I can say it's possible. I'm working on project where combined asp.net mvc and asp.net dynamic data futures.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923692%28v=VS.100%29.aspx